# Express.js using passport-facebook - TypeError: Object 302 has no method 'indexOf'

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I've got an express project already running, I'm just trying to hook it up using passport to authenticate through facebook, I've basically copied the example from the github page here:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

But I'm getting the following error whenever I try to go to the '/auth/facebook' URL in my app:

```
TypeError: Object 302 has no method 'indexOf'
    at ServerResponse.res.redirect (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:546:13)
    at Strategy.strategy.redirect (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:294:15)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/passport-facebook/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:227:10)
    at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/strategy.js:84:41)
    at attempt (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:337:16)
    at authenticate (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:338:7)
    at callbacks (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:171:11)
    at param (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:11)
    at pass (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:152:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/Users/jlawrence/Documents/Websites/Node/Gigster/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:179:5)
```

Comment: What versions of express and passport are the existing project using?

Comment: Express 3.0 and Passport 0.2.0 dude

Comment: It could be an incompatibility with older versions of express; you might try updating to express@3.5.x; 3.6 and above deprecated some methods and the refactor might not be worth it.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try, if I npm update express -g my version sits at express@3.0.0-alpha4 but still no good

Comment: If that didn't work for you, try `npm install express@3.5.x -g`, or if it's a local package that's being used in the app, `npm install express@3.5.x`

Comment: Dude, you're a legend. Upgrading to 3.5.3 and it suddenly works...what a ballache - post it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an incompatibility with older versions of express; you might try updating to express@3.5.x; 3.6 and above deprecated some methods and the refactor might not be worth it.

Try `npm install express@3.5.x`, or `npm install express@3.5.x -g` if it's a global package. Make sure to update the `package.json` file too.